# Post text box array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have text box values to be posted . How do I take it in a PHP array .

**EDIT**

```
---------------------------
    <input type="text" name="ItemName[1][2]" >
        <input type="text" name="ItemName[1][3]" >
        <input type="text" name="ItemName[1][4]" >
------------------------------
$ItemNamesArray = $_POST[] ..... ????? What do I do in this step???
```

Please help.

Comment: use json to post, and json_encode to retreive the data

Comment: why json? Is there any sense in that?

Comment: I directly pasted the html which was hidden ,now i have rectified the post ... please help now

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" name="array[]" />
<input type="text" name="array[]" />
<input type="text" name="array[]" />
<input type="text" name="array[]" />


print_r( $_POST['array'] );
```

Comment: Should also write that he can access it via $_POST['array'][0], $_POST['array'][1], ... cause trick with [] will do an array in PHP.

Comment: sir, i directly pasted the html which was hidden ,now i have recdtified the post ... please help now

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][2]" >
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][3]" >
<input type="text" name="ItemName[1][4]" >

$ItemNamesArray = $_POST['ItemName'][1];

foreach($ItemNamesArray as $item){
  var_dump($item); //this will show you the value of each item

 // do whatever you want to do (insert into a database, send an email, etc)
}
```

But I would not use a bidimensional array for this, only if ItemName is been used for another purpose on the same form.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" name="myform">
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="101"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="102"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="103"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="104"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="submit"/>
</form>



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

foreach($_POST['array'] as $myarray) {

    echo $myarray.'<br>';

}
```

## OUTPUT

```
101
102
103
104
```

Answer (score 0):

Your POST input is in $_POST array. To display it - `var_dump($_POST)`. To access its items - for example named 'textbox' - `var_dump($_POST['textbox']`;

Comment: sir, i directly pasted the html which was hidden ,now i have recdtified the post ... please help now

Comment: Not so good format. Can you change names of your `inputs` or it's impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$_REQUEST['ItemName[1][2]'];
$_REQUEST['ItemName[1][3]'];
$_REQUEST['ItemName[1][4]'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<input type="text" name="ItemName[]" >
<input type="text" name="ItemName[]" >
<input type="text" name="ItemName[]" >
```

and input to database using insert SQL :

```
// EXECUTE SQL INDEXED TEXTBOX
foreach ($_POST['itemName'] as $item)
{

$query  = "INSERT INTO  tableName (field1)";
$query .= " VALUES ('" .  $item . "')";

}
```

Comment: OP does not talk about database

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done to show you what happen when you submit :

I completed your script to show the `$_POST` var (what you click on submit) like so :

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="ItemName[1][2]" value="a">
  <input type="text" name="ItemName[1][3]" value="b">
  <input type="text" name="ItemName[1][4]" value="c">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if($_POST) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

Here is the output when I click on submit :

```
Array
(
    [ItemName] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => a
                    [3] => b
                    [4] => c
                )
        )
)
```

It show you that you have your array of values in `$_POST["ItemName"][1]` so you can do :

```
$myArrayOfValues = $_POST["ItemName"][1];
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

$_POST or $_GET is a array which the way the user can interact with web form.
In this case, I have a sample form:

```
<form method="POST" action="array.php">

 <input name="a" type="text" value="1" />
 <input name="b" type="text" value="2" />
 <input type="submit" value="Sum" />
```

action form array.php:

```
<?php   
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    echo $a + $b;
?>
```

$_POST['a'],$_POST['b'] is variable bring value of textbox, you can use in PHP Code to evaluate.

Comment: This will output '3', and does not give an array

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Form:

```
<input type="text" name="ItemName[]" value="">
```

PHP Script:

```
$ItemName = POST['ItemName'];

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($ItemName); $i++){

   $sq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ItemName`='$ItemName[$i]'");

}
```

Comment: OP does not talk about database