# Want to get value of textboxes

Tags: php, textbox

What i want to do is,

I have a code which generates 2 textboxes on a button click event througn ajax as many time as button clicks.
So On the click of submit button how can i identify textboxes and getvalue of each textbox.

So I want to give dynamic name to each text box.and on the form submit i want to fetch each textbox's value.

can i do something like this

```
<input type="text" name="fname[]" value="Hello" />
<input type="text" name="fname[]" value="World" />
```

and get value on submit

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['txtfname[]'])){
    echo $_POST['txtfname[0]'];

}
?>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Yes you can do the same

Comment: Be sure to check [Post text box array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279507/post-text-box-array-in-php)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are in the `$_POST['fname']`-array.

Meaning:

`$_POST['fname'][0]` --> "Hello"

`$_POST['fname'][1]` --> "World"

Answer (score 0):

While creating the text box as you said by a ajax give the name of the newly created button as an array as you said.And after submitting the form if you `print_r($_POST)` you could see the posted array which contains all the values of the elements submitted in the form.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible, but following is probably a better way to do it. If you generate each of the inputs so their names are in this format: `<input type="text" name="fname_0" value="value" />` where `0` is the number, you can then use this code to loop through each one and echo the value:

```
$prefix = "fname_";
foreach ($_POST as $post) {
    if (strncmp($post, $prefix, strlen($prefix))) {
        echo $post;
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Alternatively, if you format the inputs like `<input type="text" name="fname" value="value" />`, they will be accessible through `$_POST['fname']` as an array, so you can echo each one like this (in your PHP code):

```
foreach ($_POST['fname'] as $fname) {
    echo $fname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML for each of your elements put

```
<input type="text" name="fname[]" value="value" />
```

Where `value` is the value of each textbox.
This will put all of the values of each textbox inside a single array.
In the code to dump the values of all the inputs, you can put:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
    $array =  $_POST['fname'];
    var_dump($array)

}
?>
```