# Insert row from form submission, get the inserted id, then insert repeatable fields as multiple rows using the new id as a foreign key

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, insert, form-submit

I have a HTML form that I populate from database with a "foreach" loop, so the fields in the name have the same name. The data that I want to post back into the database comes from variables that are arrays. At this moment when I insert into database, I get the right TIMES of insert, only the values that are inserted (in this case 4 times) are the same values, as in the last row of the HTML form.

I tried implode, even extract values from the VAR, but I'm sure I'm on the wrong track.

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{    
    $client_id = ($value->ID);
    $qry = "INSERT INTO salesorder (client_id)
            VALUES ('$client_id')";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysql));
    $order_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysql);
    foreach ($results as $result) :  
        $food_id = $_GET['foodid'];
        print_r($food_id);
        $qty = $_GET['qty'];
        $qry="INSERT INTO orderline (order_id, food_id, qty) VALUES ($order_id, '$food_id', '$qty') ";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysql,$qry);
    endforeach; 
}
```

```
<tbody>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <?php foreach ( $results as $result ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="qty" size="2" type="number"></td>
                <td><?php print($result->food_type); ?></td>
                <td><input name="foodid[]" size="4" type="number" value=<?php print($result->food_id); ?>></td>
            <tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

This is what the form looks like:

So the form is first dynamic loaded, from the database. could be 2 lines, or 50 lines...
but my problem is, after the client fills out qty where he wants to place order off, to "read" the whole form, and load it back into the database

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: What does your HTML look like? could you share that as well?

Comment: I would expect `$_GET['foodid']` and `$_GET['qty']` to always return the same values.  If they were arrays then you'd be accessing them with an index.  What values are you sending to the server?  Where are the arrays that you mention?

Comment: thanks all, yes i know the code is wide open, i use this merely on my localhost for testing and will adapt to security before we go live.

Comment: <tbody>
     <form action="" method="GET">
  <?php foreach ( $results as $result ) : ?>
   <tr><td><input name="qty" size="2" type="number"></td>
   <td><?php print($result->food_type); ?></td>
   <td><input name="foodid[]" size="4" type="number" value=<?php print($result->food_id); ?>></td><tr>
   
  <?php
   endforeach;
  ?>
   </tbody>

Comment: You really should start by learning prepared statements. There is no reason to write this code, delete it, and write it again.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: this is what rhe form looks like. the problem is not that i cant retrieve the data from the form after input from client (qty), but to get it in a right way into the database.

Comment: sorry will do...

Comment: If `$_GET['foodid']` is an array then you need to iterate it or use keys to access the elements.

Comment: please can you explain that with an example, as that is i guess my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting an array from your HTML form then you need to loop on this array and insert each row separately into DB. To do this you need to use prepared statement and a loop.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $client_id = $value->ID; // Wherever this value comes from...

    // Insert new sales order
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare('INSERT INTO salesorder (client_id) VALUES (?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $client_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    $order_id = $mysql->insert_id;

    // prepare the SQL statement
    $orderline_stmt = $mysql->prepare('INSERT INTO orderline (order_id, food_id, qty) VALUES (?,?,?)');

    // loop on each element from HTML form 
    // i.e. <input name="foodid[]" >
    foreach ($_GET['foodid'] as $key => $food_id) {
        $qty = $_GET['qty']; // should this be an array too?
        // $qty = $_GET['qty'][$key]; <-- if it's also an array

        $orderline_stmt->bind_param('sss', $order_id, $food_id, $qty);
        $orderline_stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: We want a transaction here, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what your HTML looks like but having the same name for all your inputs does not neccessarily mean they have become an array. you will need to define them as array in HTML using `[]`. Below is an example

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="myform">
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="101"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="102"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="103"/>
<input type="text" name="array[]" Value="104"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

foreach($_POST['array'] as $myarray) {

    echo $myarray.'<br>';

}
```

this should get you the unique values from each input and then you do what you want with it.

Here is a link to several other solutions that could help: [Post text box array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279507/post-text-box-array-in-php)